# ERROR: Attribute '' cannot be parsed: Cannot read property 'dataType' of undefined

Tags: sequelize-cli

I was creating document_types table using following cli command

```
sequelize model:create --name User --attributes name:string, username:string, email:string, password:string
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Solution: remove the space after comma between different attributes to avoid the error, correct command would be:

```
sequelize model:create --name User --attributes name:string,username:string,email:string,password:string
```